# Split a html file into different parts using express

Tags: node.js, express

I am a beginner in express and node, coming from a PHP background. What I used to do in PHP, split a file into `header.php`, `footer.php`, sidebar.php etc.

And finally, include them in a `index.php` or other pages. Is there any way I can do it using express. I am using node and express to serve a HTML file.

All I want is to split them into header.html, footer.html etc and add them in index.html or other pages. Currently, I can serve only a single HTML file using express and node. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pick a template engine to do something like that. Here is a list that you can pick:

- [hogan](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/)
- [jade](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html/)
- [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: I am giving them a look.

Comment: thanks but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I have found a embeddedjs, which serves exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easier than you think.

Follow the link :
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

The templating engine used there is Pug(upgraded version of jade). You may also choose to use any other one too like that Handlebars, EJS etc.